# Get absolute screen coordinates of a div inside a webview on Android

Tags: android, android-webview, jchartfx

I have a complex chart (jChartFx) created using javascript inside a webview on Android. I need to be able to export this chart to a png file.

I've tried using html2canvas but the chart is rendered using svg which is not supported, so my next try is to get the exact screen coordinates of the chart and then from native code in Android create a screenshot of that section. But I don't know how to get the coordinates.

Does anynone knows how to do this? Does anyone have another idea?

Note: I also tried using canvg after reading this (http://community.jchartfx.com/topic/101-exporting-a-chart-to-an-image/) but wasn't able to get it working.